# Why can't Windows 7 run on System-on-a-Chip (SoC)?

Tags: windows-7

Microsoft announced that the next version of Windows will run on SoC, what is the technical reason for this being big news? Why couldn't Windows 7 do it?

Answer (score 2):

The point isn't so much SoCs, but rather that those are usually ARM-based. Windows is available for x86, x68-64 and maybe still IA-64 but no other platforms. Therefore the big news here is that there is a native Windows build including all components and included applications that runs on ARM CPUs which use an instruction set different from x86.

Comment: 1. No consumer version of Windows (including Win7) has ever been able to run on the Itanium (IA-64) or ever will be; and the last server version to support it will be 2008 R2. 2. I think you meant x86 on the end there :)